# Enviar dados para outra página ou enviar para mesma?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se é melhor, por exemplo, ter um form em que é setado o action para outra página, ou se é recomendado enviar os dados para a própria página com o `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`.

Caso vocês não tenham entendido, seria mais ou menos assim, devo utilizar qual destes dois métodos:

**Enviar para mesma página:**

```
<form name="login_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="login_form">
```

E então no topo eu faço uma verificação:

```
if(isset($_POST['logar'])): 
//Código
endif;
```

Ou eu deveria:

**Enviar para outra página:**

```
<form name="login_form" action="checarLogin.php" method="post" id="login_form">
```

E fazer a validação e sanitização naquela página em específico.

Com melhor, eu pergunto sobre segurança, velocidade, e viabilidade também.

Comment: eu acredito que em relação à performance, seria a mesma, segurança também. Porém em questões de organização de código seria bem melhor você separar, para deixar o seu código mais legível.

Comment: Nunca utilize `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`, isto é cria uma vulnerabilidade por XSS, se for na mesma página especifique-a por exemplo "login.php" e não `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ou se ainda quiser usar o `PHP_SELF` utilize `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");`!

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas pessoal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandar para outro script tende a deixar seu código mais organizado, deixando ele mais viável para futuras edições.

Em questão de velocidade quanto menos redirecionamentos mais rápido será, porém apenas mais um redirecionamento não irá mudar muita coisa, dependendo muito do que você está tentando fazer.

E em questão de segurança na minha opinião esse tipo de coisa não influência.